# How to get HID ID using Input Function?

Tags: python, input, hid

Use case description:

I have three physical locations to put products into, within one meter of each other.  All products have a barcode.  I have a computer, monitor and barcode scanner at each location.

The PCs are kiosks, when a barcode is scanned there's an API call to move the product to the location the PC is assigned to.

```
location =  'location_1'
while True:
    serial_no = input('Scan a barcode...') # barcode scanned gives the serial number
    api_call(location, serial_No)
```

I want to have one PC and three barcode scanners, something like this:

```
while True:
    scan_data = input('Scan a barcode...') 
    if scan_data.HID_name == 'scanner_1':
        location = 'location_1'
    if scan_data.HID_name == 'scanner_2':
        location = 'location_2'
    if scan_data.HID_name == 'scanner_3':
        location = 'location_3'
    serial_no = scan_data.input_data
    api_call(location, serial_No)
```

I've Googled and seen ways to get HID device names but nothing similar enough to apply.

Is there a `library` or way to extend the `input()` function to achieves this?

Comment: `input()` just returns a string with no information about where it came from. You'll need to use an API that allows you to read directly from each scanner, so you can tell which one was used.